# ggplot2 cumulative percent graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, percentage

I am attempting to create a cumulative % graph so that all the values = 100% on the y axis.

Here is the code:

```
dmScat <- data.frame(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6))

colnames(dmScat) <- c("c")

ggplot(dmScat,
       aes(x=sort(c),
           y=1:length(c)),)+
  geom_point(shape=1, colour = "Orange")+
  labs(x="DM %",y="Cumulative %")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
```

I just want it to be 0% to 100% for all data.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood the question correctly (though an example of the expected output would be helpful), the following might help:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(x = 0:6)

d <- d %>% mutate(percent = 100/n() * 1:n())

ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = percent)) +
  geom_area() +
  geom_point(color = "lightblue", size = 5) +
  labs(x = "X variable", y = "Cumulative %") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: You've got it! Just wanted to mention that you may want x = sort(x) as my data wasn't in order!

Also I made the mistake of using theme_bw() and now it won't stop appearing! Any idea how to remove the blackness below the points?

Comment: If you're happy to keep using `dplyr`, add `arrange(x)` into the pipe before `mutate()` to sort by `x`. The "blackness" is created by `geom_area()`. Take that out and you'll just get the points. If you want to add a line joining the points, add `geom_line()`

Comment: Cheer M8 your a legend +1

Comment: Wait actually it didn't remove the black... haha

Still gave +1 for the stuff that mattered! haha

Comment: Haha, glad to help! But strange that removing `geom_area()` doesn't remove the black. E.g., for me, `ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = percent)) + geom_point(color = "lightblue", size = 5)` doesn't give any black. Anyway, as long as you can work with it.